# T-SQL merging 2 rows into 1

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table where I end up with two rows but I need a total of the data from both rows in one row, I can't use group by as I'm getting the usual must be in select list or contained in the group by clause.

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE 

(
FirstName NVARCHAR(10)
,Ref NVARCHAR (4)
,UserName NVARCHAR(30)
,File1 INT
,File2 INT
,ID INT
,Active Bit DEFAULT 0


)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('John','AAAB','AAA Admin',5,10,677,1)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('John (P)','AAAC','AAAC Admin',6,15,765,1)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('John Admin','AAAG','AAA Admin',6,15,765,0)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('Jane','AAUD','AAA Admin',6,15,765,0)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('Jenny','AAOZ','AAA Admin',6,15,765,0)

;WITH CTE
 AS
 (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by FirstName Order by ID) RN
    from @Test
 )
 SELECT * FROM CTE
 WHERE RN=1 AND Active = 1
 ORDER BY ID DESC

[![Results][1]][1]
```

[image]

The File1 and File2 Values from INSERTS 3,4,5 are duplicate data and aren't required in the result.

Text :

```
FirstName   Ref UserName    File1   File2   ID  Active  RN
John (P)    AAAC    AAAC Admin  6   15  765 1   1
John    AAAB    AAA Admin   5   10  677 1   1
```

Expected Output:

[image]

Comment: Can you paste the expected output as text

Comment: I expect to get 1 row with File1 and File2 as a Total with either FirstName or should I say I would like to get.

Comment: What about other columns Ref, UserName?

Comment: I don't need them , just something to indicate its John in the FirstName and I'm only after the FirstName and  File columns in the results. I just put the other stuff in there to show what I'd got to work with, I've tried a temp table and manipulating it that way but to no avail.

Comment: How do you know `john` and `john (P)` are same?

Comment: If you comment out the where clause row number RN will be from 1-4 for first 4 rows and then 1 again for row 5, I'm looking for RN = 1

Comment: John and John (P) are different. They'll never group together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want.

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE 
(
FirstName NVARCHAR(10)
,Ref NVARCHAR (4)
,UserName NVARCHAR(30)
,File1 INT
,File2 INT
,ID INT
,Active Bit DEFAULT 0
)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('John','AAAB','AAA Admin',5,10,677,1)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('John (P)','AAAC','AAAC Admin',6,15,765,1)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('John Admin','AAAG','AAA Admin',6,15,765,0)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('Jane','AAUD','AAA Admin',6,15,765,0)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('Jenny','AAOZ','AAA Admin',6,15,765,0)

;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        IIF(Tmp = 0, A.FirstName, SUBSTRING(A.FirstName, 0, A.Tmp)) FirstName,
        A.File1,
        A.File2
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            *,
            CHARINDEX(' ', FirstName, 0) Tmp
        FROM 
            @Test
        WHERE
            Active = 1
    ) A
)   

SELECT
    A.FirstName,
    SUM(A.File1) File1,
    SUM(A.File2) File2
FROM
    CTE A
GROUP BY    
    A.FirstName
```

Result:

```
FirstName   File1   File2
John        11      25
```

Comment: What you've supplied has done the job, I had a few other columns to SUM , I put ROW_NUMBER OVER (PARTITION BY ) in CTE A under  A.File2 or my equivalent and added WHERE RowNumber = 1 in the outer where clause , it worked fine, thxs.